Closed complement of an open immersion of rigid analytic spaces
I am new to rigid analytic spaces (over non-archimedean fields) and I am confused about the notions of closed and open immersions. My question is are these two notions are "complement" of each other like the case of schemes? I know that this is the case at least when we have a closed immersion $Z \hookrightarrow X$ then we have an open complement defined set-theoretically by $U = X \setminus Z$ and we can endow $U$ with a rigid structure so that the inclusion $U \hookrightarrow X$ is an open immersion (= an admissible open). For instance, the standard example that I keep in mind for this case is the puncture disk inside the Tate unit ball (which is the complement of the origin), which is a union of annuli with increasing radii. However, I am doubtful about the reverse direction: given an admissible open $U \subset X$, can we endow $Z = X \setminus U$ with a rigid structure so that the inclusion $Z \hookrightarrow X$ is a closed immersion of rigid spaces?
Update: In case $Z$ cannot be given a structure such that $Z \hookrightarrow X$ is a closed immersion. Is $Z$ still a rigid space? For example, this is a case that I am particularly interested in: let $R = k[[t]]$, $K = k((t))$ with $k$ a field, let $X$ be a $R$-variety, then there is an open immersion $(\hat{X})_{\eta} \hookrightarrow (X_K)^{\text{an}}$ from the Raynaud's generic fiber of the $t$-adic completion $\hat{X}$ into the analytification of $X_K$? Is $(X_K)^{\text{an}} \setminus (\hat{X})_{\eta}$ a rigid space? If so, can we write down a concrete admissible covering?

No, you cannot, and this is indicative of an important reality: rigid geometry acts quite differently from algebraic geometry. Let me interpret your question in turns of adic geometry, as this is more clarifying in my opinion. If $X=\mathbb{D}^1_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ is the closed unit disk over $\mathbb{C}_p$. There is a classification of the points of $X$ into five types. This is recorded quite clearly in Example 2.20 of Scholze's paper Perfectoid Spaces. I will assume you will look there for the meaning of the following terms. Let $x$ be a point of Type 5 in $X$. Then, $x$ is closed.

That said, there is no adic space $Z$ and morphism $f\colon Z\to X$ whose image is ${x}$. The reason is that $Z$ is necessarily an analytic adic space (as it would admit a map to $X$ which is analytic) and then we use the following fact which greatly separates algebraic and analytic geometry: any map of analytic adic spaces is generalizing (e.g., see Lemma 1.1.10 of Huber's book on etale cohomology). In particular, what this tells us is that if $f(z)=x$ then $f(G(z))=G(x)$, where $G(-)$ denotes the set of generalizations of the point in the relevant space.

But, we run into obvious trouble. Namely, $G(x)$ contains a unique point of Type 2, but this cannot possible be in $f(G(z))\subseteq f(Z)={x}$.
Of course, this is not an issue for some closed subsets (e.g., Zariski closed ones), but this issue is also why Huber defines the notion of a 'pseudo-adic space'. This essentially is an adic space $X$ and a (topologically nice) subset $S$ such that the 'geometry of $(X,S)$ approximates the geometry of $S$'.

If $Z\subseteq X$ is generalizing, then you can at least endow it with some geometric structure: that of a small v-sheaf (a la Scholze). Namely, you can consider $X\times_{|X|}|Z|$, where for a space $T$ we take $|T|(S):=\mathrm{Hom}_\mathrm{cont.}(|S|,|T|)$ for a perfectoid space $S$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Hi Alex Youcis, this is a bit out of my knowledge but I guess the answer is negative but is $Z = X \setminus U$ in my post still a rigid space? A particular case that I care most, given a $R$-variety $X$ with $R=k[[t]]$ then there is an open immersion $(\hat{X}){\eta} \hookrightarrow (X_K)^{an}$ (with $K = k((t))$, $\hat{X}$ the $t$-adic completion and $\eta$ is Raynaud generic fiber), can we write down an admissible covering of the complement $(X_K)^{an} \setminus (\hat{X}){\eta}$? You can write an answer so that I can accept it.

Hey Alexey, the answer is no, although the explanation is a little more complicated. Namely, take $X=\mathbb{A}^1_{k[![t]!]}$. Then what you are describing is the inclusion $\mathbb{D}^1_{k(!(t)!)}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^{1,\mathrm{an}}{k(!(t)!)}$. If $\eta$ is the Gauss point of the closed unit disk, then it is 'missing' the 'upward pointing' Type 5 point. So, this Type 5 point is in the complement $\mathbb{A}^{1,\mathrm{an}}{k(!(t)!)}-\mathbb{D}^1_{k(!(t)!)}$ but it has the Gauss point as a generalization, and so this complement is not generalizing so the same issue holds.

It's late here, and so I will double-check this tomorrow, and post it as an answer.

No, it's not true that if $X$ is a rigid $K$-space and $U\subseteq X$ is open, that $Z:=X-U$ can be given the structure of an adic space (let alone a rigid $K$-space) such that the tautological map $i\colon Z\to X$ of topological spaces upgrades to a morphism of adic spaces.
The issue is that morphisms of analytic adic spaces (note any adic space over $X$ is analytic as $X$ is) are generalizing. Namely, suppose that $f\colon Y\to X$ is a morphism of analytic adic spaces. Then, [Huber, Lemma 1.1.10] shows that for any $y$ in $Y$ with $x=f(y)$ the equality $f(G_Y(y))=G_X(x)$ holds. Here $G_S(s)$ denotes the set of generalizations of the point $s$ in the space $S$.
So, if $i\colon Z\to X$ could be upgraded to a map of adic spaces, then $Z$ would be need to be generalizing: if $z\in Z$ then we'd have that $Z\supseteq i(G_Z(z))=G_X(z)$. Equivalently, we would have to have that $U\subseteq X$ is a so-called overconvergent (aka partially proper, aka Berkovich) open subset. This just means that $U$ is closed under specializations. Note that this is quite restrictive. For instance, if $U\to X$ is quasi-compact then $U$ is actually clopen (e.g., apply [Fujiwara--Kato, Chapter 0, Corollary 2.2.27]).
So, let's consider a concrete example conforming to your stated interests. Let $\mathcal{X}=\mathbb{A}^1_{k[[t]]}$, and let $\widehat{\mathcal{X}}$ be its $t$-adic completion. Then, as per usual (e.g., see [Huber, §1.9]) we have an open embedding $\widehat{\mathcal{X}}_\eta\hookrightarrow \mathcal{X}_\eta^\mathrm{an}$. In this case this concretely corresponds to the open embedding $\mathbb{D}^1_{k((t))}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{A}^{1,\mathrm{an}}_{k((t))}$. The complement of this open embedding does not have the structure of an adic space as $\mathbb{D}^1_{k((t))}$ is not an overconvergent open in $\mathbb{A}^{1,\mathrm{an}}_{k((t))}$. One no-thinking way to see this based off what I said above: this inclusion is quasi-compact but the image is not closed. More concretely, this open subset is not closed under specialization since its image is missing the 'outward facing Type 5 point' around the Gauss point (I am using terminology from [Scholze, Example 2.20]).
So, what to do? There are two options:
(1) one can try to utilize Huber's theory of pseudo-adic spaces (see [Huber]) which essentially tries to develop the geometry of (certain) subsets of an adic space even when they do not themselves possess the structure of an adic space,
(2) when $Z\subseteq X$ is generalizing, there is always a diamond $Z^\lozenge$ (in the sense of [Scholze2]) and a map $Z^\lozenge\to X^\lozenge$ recovers the map $Z\to X$ on topological spaces. Namely, one takes $Z^\lozenge:=X\times_{|X|}|Z|$, with notation as in [AGLR, §2.1].
EDIT: Given my impression of your interests, it may be worth noting that the (etale topos of the) pseudo-adic space of $Z$ does form the closed complement of the open subtopos $U_\mathrm{et}\subseteq X_\mathrm{et}$ (e.g., see [Huber, Lemma 2.3.11]). I would guess this is enough for your purposes.
References:
[Fujiwara--Kato] Fujiwara, K. and Kato, F., 2018. Foundations of rigid geometry I.
[Huber] Huber, R., 2013. Étale cohomology of rigid analytic varieties and adic spaces (Vol. 30). Springer.
[Scholze] Scholze, P., 2012. Perfectoid spaces. Publications mathématiques de l'IHÉS, 116(1), pp.245-313.
[Scholze2] Scholze, P., 2017. Étale cohomology of diamonds. arXiv preprint arXiv:1709.07343.

Hi Alex, thanks for the answer. Btw, we met in Hanoi few months ago, I was the guy saying that your blog is useful for me in the first day. I still wait for the second part of your blog post on rigid geometry.

@AlexeyDo ah of course! It’s a little hard to find time these days. But I do hope to do it at some point. :)

What more could we say about that in terms of analytic stacks?

@Z.M Truth be told, I don't really know the first thing about analytic stacks. Maybe somebody else could say.

@AlexYoucis, Hi Alex, sorry for digging since I just saw your edit. So as far as I understand, $Z$ is something you called pseudo-adic? How's about if we forget the relation between $Z$ and $X$? Can $Z$ be an analytic space in any sense?

@AlexeyDo Hey. Can you say what you mean precisely? Do you mean is there an adic space and a map $Z’\to X$ which has image $Z$? I think my answer shows that is impossible. It is possible for $Z$ to be a pseudo-adic space as I said, but this is not giving $Z$ the structure of an adic space, but is the next best thing (although it depends on the tuple $(X,Z)$, although the etale topos is more flexible).

Hi Alexis, what I mean is can we endow $Z$ with a structure of a rigid analytic space? I don't care whether $Z$ is a closed subspace of $X$ or there exists a map $Z' \to X$, I just care about $Z$ itself. Of course, the structure should not be so arbitrary. Someone tolds me that from the point of view of Berkovich spaces, this is possible but according to your answer, it is not possible so I don't really know who is right about this.

@AlexeyDo I’m not sure what the other person said. Maybe if you could be more specific about what they mean, I could say, but I don’t really see how that would be possible. It’s possible what they mean is that the complement in the Berkovich space is OPEN not closed. Namely, in the example with the close disk above, at the level of the berkovich spaces this is a closed embedding and so its complement is an open, not a closed. Is this related to what you mean?

@AlexYoucis, ok that makes sense. So in the Berkovich world, everything changes? At first I thought it is just a different pov to treat same spaces.

@AlexeyDo Everything changes but only superficially. Like, it's analogous to saying that for a finite type K-algebra R, that two subsets $S,T\subseteq \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ can have the property that $S\cap \mathrm{MaxSpec}(R)=T\cap\mathrm{MaxSpec}(R)$ while also $S\ne T$. Like in this MaxSpec world you are missing points, and so set-theoretic equality can be misleading (this is an issue of constructability of $S,T$ , but this is also what's happening secretly in this rigid world). In particular, the complement in the Berkovich world misses a higher rank point in the complement

in the adic world. So, you can work in this Berkovich world and if you have something like an open/closed decomposition of topoi, things are fine, but you have to work a priori harder because this missing point contains information. But, in the end, there is no actual contradiction because this open/closed decomposition for the pseudo-adic space $Z$ should roughly capture the same information as the open/closed decomposition of topoi in this Berkovich world.

So in short: they are different points of view, but some care must be taken in the change of perspectives, similar to 'classical varieties' vs. 'schemes' change of view.
